# Балансировка нагрузки OSPF Cisco packet tracer

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer, ospf

Всем доброго времени суток! Присутствует следующая топология:
[image: топология]

Необходимо только средствами OSPF, не меняя bandwidth, cost и не используя пассивные интерфейсы произвести балансировку между Router12 и Router10. Все маршрутизаторы на данный момент находятся в одной зоне (area 0).

Нашел [похожий вопрос](https://forum.nag.ru/index.php?/topic/142013-ospf-mikrotik-balansirovka-nagruzki-kanalov/), но для microtik и без чёткого ответа. Буду безумно благодарен за помощь!